# Get gameogject names in array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

How to I can use specific game objects in an array by names on `if();` operator ?
I now that, cannot implicitly convert type `string[]' to string'`, but must be another way?

```
List <GameObject> cubes = new List<GameObject> ();

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);


            cubes.Add (coll.gameObject);

            string[] ar1 = {"a1","a2" ,"a3","a4"};

            if (cubes.Count > 4) {

                foreach(GameObject go in cubes){

                    if (go.name == ar1) {

                        Debug.Log ("PASSED");
                    }

                }
```

Comment: This is a little unclear.

Comment: when spesific gameobjects in array is OnCollisionEnter , it must be worked.

Comment: I want to get gameobject names in array on ' if() '  oprator

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments, I see what you're asking:
How can you check if all the objects with the names specified in `ar1` are in the `cubes` list?

I would do it like so:

```
List<string> ar1 = new List<string>() {"a1","a2","a3","a4"};
List<string> cubeNames = new List<string>();

foreach(GameObject go in cubes) {
    cubeNames.Add(go.name);
}

if (aIsSubsetOfB(ar1, cubeNames)) {
    Console.WriteLine("PASSED");
}

bool isASubsetOfB(List<string> a, List<string> b) {
    foreach(string element in a) {
        if (!isAinB(element, b)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool doesBcontainA(string a, List<string> b) {
    foreach(string element in b) {
        if (element == a) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have added the methods `isASubsetOfB` and `doesBcontainA` for convenience and code clarity

Comment: this is working when one of gameobjects in array in OnCollisionEnter. I want to get all gameobjects in array if OncollisionEnter

Comment: So you want to check if the cubes with the names in `ar1` are in your `cubes` List?